# How do I make a bootstrap container a fixed size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4. This is my html :

```
<div class="sprite container d-inline-block bg-info rounded p-1">
   <span class="sprite-span-level">Top-right text over image</span>
   <img class="sprite-img" src="someimage">
   <span class="sprite-span-nickname">text under image</span>
</div>
```

This is my CSS :

```
.sprite{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.sprite-span-level{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
.sprite-img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

The end result looks like this : https://jsfiddle.net/f7u9k5so/.
What I would like is forcing the image to a certain size, and having the container div fit accordingly. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to change the width of the container to a certain size but keep the size of the image 100% (which will try to cover whole container).

You just need to specify width for your container and the image size will change accordingly to your container size.

```
.container {
   width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, it worked. I wrote something wrong. Thanks !